# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I have written the following code in JAVA using Selenium web driver using both Internet Explorer and Firefox. Everytime I am getting the same error. Tried using both "id" and "xpath" method, but still it is failing. Tried adding some delay also, still does not work.

My JAVA code for Firefox:

```
package ieconnector;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class FireFoxConnector {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
    GetBrowserProperty gbp = new GetBrowserProperty();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",gbp.getIeConnection());
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\softwares\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver wb = new FirefoxDriver();
    Capabilities caps = ((RemoteWebDriver) wb).getCapabilities();
    System.out.println("Caps is "+caps);
    wb.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //wb.navigate().to("https://somewebsite.com:22222/SSO/ui/SSOLogin.jsp");
    wb.get("https://somewebsite.com:22222/SSO/ui/SSOLogin.jsp");
    wb.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    wb.manage().window().maximize();
    //wb.findElement(By.id("usertxt")).sendKeys(("user").toUpperCase());
    //wb.findElement(By.className("passtxt")).sendKeys("password");
    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wb,10);
    //WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("usertxt")));
    wb.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //wb.findElement(By.id("usertxt")).sendKeys("USER");
    wb.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='usertxt']")).sendKeys("USER");
    System.out.println("Testing is successful");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

}

And the following is a screenshot of the HTML code in my developer tool in IE/Firefox.

[image: HTML]

Comment: Can you try this code`new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='usertxt']")));` before trying to perform SendKeys.

Comment: Could you share the error/exception trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the HTML you have shared to locate the *User ID* field you can use the following solution:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  wb.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.txtbox#usertxt")).sendKeys("USER");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  wb.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='txtbox' and @id='usertxt']")).sendKeys("USER");
  ```